# Invoke-Command run a script in a driver

Tags: powershell-remoting

I create a new remote session with powershell, in this way:

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("computername\admin", $securePassword)
try { 
        $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName "computername" -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $credential
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName computername -FilePath "M:\revertToSnapshot Release1.ps1"
Remove-PSSession $s
```

and I don't figure out how can I run a script in the M drive.

If I try with the following:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName jm_ci -FilePath "m:\revertTosnapshot release1.ps1"
```

I got the following error: Invoke-Command : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'm' does not exist.

The user is a computer administrator.

Comment: Is the M: drive mapped correctly for the account that the remote powershell session is using and does that account have sufficient privileges to access that drive ?

Comment: and if you log on to that machine as administrator and run a cmd prompt, does the command dir "M:\revertToSnapshot Release1.ps1" work as expected?

Comment: Why are you creating a new-pssession? invoke-command doesn't needed it.

Comment: maybe I read a bad example... how can I use the section?